# Face tracking during live recording

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I was trying to make it possible for simultaneously using camera.startFaceDetection 
and mediaRecorder.start.

But it always crashed, is there have any ideal for this scenario?

I was wondering whether if it is possible to face tracking during media recording.

regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes I believe it is possible (certainly on ICS), I'm not sure however it's possible with the MediaRecorder.

The ICS camera application has it's own EffectsRecorder.java class (which is why I suspect the MediaRecorder won't work) that is based on the media recorder programming model. The graphs it uses for the Goofy face effects live in goofy_face.graph in packages/apps/Camera/res/raw/goofy_face.graph. You can find these files in the ICS SDK.

I have had quite a lot of joy by modifying the filter graph in system/media/mca/samples/CameraEffectsRecordingSample to create and use my own effects.

Note: on my Nexus S I get the goofy face effects BUT not the background replacement ones, I think you'll need some hardware support for this work correctly.

Comment: Hi Peterl, thanks a lot, I make it! It's fine to use camera.startFaceDetection during mediaRecorder on my Nexus S.